# $(document).ready(function(){ executed every time on onclick event of Hyperlink?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

In my  code I'm creating a  product list dynamically using **PHP**(see image) and the currosponding `labels and image paths` are stored into **hidden fields**(`created dynamically` using PHP) now on **document.ready()** method i set the first list item's `imagepath  to img's src` and its remarks to `label remarks` using first hidden fields for remark and imagepath.

and on listitem click i want to change it my function set these values to img and label  rightly(checked using alerts) but when function ends it set the image src and remarks innertext to default that is set on  document.ready() method

now my question is can i prevent the document.ready() to be executed next time on javascript function call

**My View :** 
As the images are reloaded so the page rendering is done again so the document.ready is called again and set these values again to default.

**Note :**

**My page is not reloading any time only images and labels are being changed**

The listshown in image is just one group other group is also created dynamically .

[image: Product list with remark and images]

**server side code in PHP**

```
<?php 
for($j=0;$j<count($productstr);$j++) { 
$valuerem = $productstr[$j]["pcode"];
$idrem  = "rem".$j.$grp;
$valueimg =$productstr[$j]["imgpath"];
$idimg = "img".$j.$grp;
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$valuerem' id='$idrem' />" ;
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$valueimg' id='$idimg' />" ;
}?>
<script>   
   $(document).ready(function() {
    idrv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > = 'rem0<?PHP echo $grp; ?>';
    idmv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > = 'img0<?PHP echo $grp; ?>';
    $('#txt<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').text(document.getElementById(idrv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? ).value);
    alert($('#txt<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').text());
    $('#img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').attr('src', document.getElementById(idmv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > ).value);
    alert($('#img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').attr('src'));
  });

  function Change(id) {
    idrv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > = 'rem' + id;
    idmv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > = 'img' + id;
    $('#txt<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').text(document.getElementById(idrv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > ).value);
    alert($('#txt<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').text());
    $('#img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').attr('src', document.getElementById(idmv < ? PHP echo $grp; ? > ).value);
    alert($('#img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').attr('src'));
    return true;
  }​
</script>
```

**alerts are used just to test the values**

**the code that are being generated at client browser**

```
 <tr>
    <td width="220px" valign="top" align="left">
    <input id="YN" type="hidden" value="true">
    <input id="rem00" type="hidden" value="SPL FUNNEL 1">
    <input id="img00" type="hidden" value="adminpanel/product_images/4f8e530154d74155.jpg">
    <input id="rem10" type="hidden" value="SPL FUNNEL 2">
    <input id="img10" type="hidden" value="adminpanel/product_images/4f8e53daf13e6156.jpg">
    <input id="rem20" type="hidden" value="SPL FUNNEL 3">
    <input id="img20" type="hidden" value="adminpanel/product_images/4f8e543100eaf157.jpg">
    <input id="rem30" type="hidden" value="SPL FUNNEL 4">
    <input id="img30" type="hidden" value="adminpanel/product_images/4f8e545a829e1158.jpg">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        idrv0 = 'rem00';
        idmv0 = 'img00';
        $('#txt0').text(document.getElementById(idrv0).value);
        alert($('#txt0').text());
        $('#img0').attr('src', document.getElementById(idmv0).value);
        alert($('#img0').attr('src'));
    });

    function Change(id) {
        $('#YN').val('false');
        idrv0 = 'rem' + id;
        idmv0 = 'img' + id;
        $('#txt0').text(document.getElementById(idrv0).value);
        alert($('#txt0').text());
        $('#img0').attr('src', document.getElementById(idmv0).value);
        alert($('#img0').attr('src'));
        return true;
    }​
    </script>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a id="00" style="text-decoration: none; text-size: 1.1em; color: " 
onclick=" Change(this.id); alert($('#txt0').text()); alert($('#img0').attr('src'));">
SPL FUNNEL 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom" align="left" colspan="2">
    <td width="110px" valign="bottom" align="left" style="width: 180px">
    </tr>
```

Comment: +1 for the awesome descriptiveness of the hand-draw MS-Paint spray circle. On-topic, `$(document).ready()` shouldn't fire more than once unless you refresh the page, could you show us some of your JS?

Comment: Picture is nice, but how about showing the relevant code too?

Comment: @thecodeparadox : no my page is not reloaded only using js i just change the src of image and innertext of label

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : ya my page is not refreshed but the image's src is being changed so the page is rerendered so that document.ready() is recalled i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna take a guess that each time you're clicking an anchor, its executing a new page load. If so, you likely need to add **preventDefault** to the anchors **onClick method**.

Assuming that your code looks something like this, add the **preventDefault()** where appropriate:

```
$('a.availableProducts').click(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   //do image stuff or whatever
});
```

Comment: Throwing error

TypeError: $(this).preventDefault is not a function

Comment: but i can not call this type of function coz i don't know the id of the hyperlink i get it from this.id see this onclick=" Change(this.id);"

Comment: added a var for the event function being passed in. Should work on that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to stop the reload on click like below.

```
$('a.availableProducts').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // your code
});
```

Comment: Throwing error TypeError: $(this).preventDefault is not a function

Comment: but i can not call this type of function coz i don't know the id of the hyperlink i get it from this.id 
see this onclick=" Change(this.id);"

Answer (score 1):

> now my question is can i prevent the document.ready() to be executed
>   next time on javascript function call

The `(document).ready()` should only be used to detect page load. It will also fire if you load and append HTML to the DOM (via ajax for example) that contains a `(document).ready()` inside.

`(document).ready()` is a way of you to tell jQuery (execute this code when the DOM is loaded and scriptable). This way you don't need to put the javascript in the end of the HTML to be sure everything is already loaded (although it's still a good practice).

Comment: yes my hidden fields are created dynamically see whole code so doesn't work on onload ,method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support of others and thanks for their answers but none of the answer gave me solution

a different approach solved my problem

My problem has been solved doing this

**Server Side code**

```
<tr>
    <td width="220px" align="left" valign="top"><?php for($j=0;$j<count($productstr);$j++)
    {
        $valuerem = $productstr[$j]["remark"];
        $idrem  = "rem".$j.$grp;
        $valueimg =$productstr[$j]["imgpath"];
        $idimg = "img".$j.$grp;
        $valuepid = $productstr[$j]["pid"];
        $idpid ="pid".$j.$grp;
        $image = $productstr[0]["imgpath"];
        $remark = $productstr[0]["remark"];
        $pid = $productstr[0]["pid"];
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='$valuerem' id='$idrem' />" ;
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='$valueimg' id='$idimg' />" ;
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='$valuepid' id='$idpid' />" ;
    }
    ?> <script>
    txt = '#txt<?PHP echo $grp; ?>';
    img = '#img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>';
    alink = '#aimg<?PHP echo $grp; ?>';
    function Change<?PHP echo $grp; ?>(id){                                                                             
        idrv<?PHP echo $grp; ?> = 'rem'+id;
        idmv<?PHP echo $grp; ?> = 'img'+id;
        idpv<?PHP echo $grp; ?> = 'pid'+id;
        $('#txt<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').html(document.getElementById(idrv<?PHP echo $grp; ?>).value);
        $('#img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').attr('src',document.getElementById(idmv<?PHP echo $grp; ?>).value);
        $('#aimg<?PHP echo $grp; ?>').attr('href',"view_large.php?mid="+document.getElementById(idpv<?PHP echo $grp; ?>).value);                                                                            
        return false;
        }   
    </script>
    <ul>
    <?php for($j=0;$j<count($productstr);$j++){
        $imgarray[ $productstr[$j]["imgpath"].'#'.$productstr[$j]["pid"]]  = $j+1;
        ?>
        <li><a id='<?PHP echo $j.$grp;?>'
            onclick="Change<?PHP echo $grp; ?>(this.id);"
            style="text-decoration: none; text-size: 1.3em; cursor: pointer;"
            title='Click to see'> <?php echo
            $productstr[$j]["pcode"]; ?> </a></li>
            <?php } $randomdata = array_rand($imgarray,1); $randompic = explode('#',$randomdata);
            ?>
    </ul>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="bottom" colspan="2"><label
        id="txt<?PHP
        echo $grp; ?>"><?PHP echo $remark; ?></label></td>
    <td width="110px" align="left" valign="bottom" style="width: 180px"><span
        class="color-4_inner p1" style="text-align: center;"> <a
        id="aimg<?PHP echo $grp; ?>"
        href="view_large.php?mid=<?PHP echo $pid; ?>"
        onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'ajax'} )"> <img
        title='Click to view Full image!' id="img<?PHP echo $grp; ?>"
        src="<?PHP echo $image; ?>" border="0" width="102" height="110" /> </a>
    </span></td>
</tr>
```